# add alias for localhost in /etc/hosts using Augeas

Tags: configuration, augeas

I am trying to use `augtool` to auto edit my `/etc/hosts`, as I wish to add an alias for localhost (so that I can test my webserver with a different host-name, localy).

I have been looking every-ware to find good documentation.

I with to find the node with `ipaddr` of `127.0.0.1` and add an alias to it.
I would also like to find some good documentation to Augeas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding an alias to a host is not really hard, what's usually more interesting is to ensure a host entry has an alias, i.e. make the operation idempotent.

Here is how you can do that with Augeas:

```
set /files/etc/hosts/*[ipaddr="127.0.0.1"]/alias[.="mycouchdb"] "mycouchdb"
```

which will only add the alias if it doesn't exist yet.

**Explanation:**

`alias[.="mycouchdb"]` refers to the alias with value `mycouchdb` (since `.` refers to the current node).

When there is no alias yet with value `mycouchdb`, `alias[.="mycouchdb"]` will not match anything and Augeas will create a node with label `alias` and value `mycouchdb`. The rule when the node doesn't exist is to use the path label without filters, in this case `alias`, so it creates a new label node and assigns it the value `mycouchdb`

When there is an alias already, the expression will match and the set command will replace the value with `mycouchdb`, which will do nothing.

Comment: That seems to work, but can you explain how. I am stuck on `alias[.="mycouchdb"]`.

Comment: `alias[.="mycouchdb"]` refers to the alias with value `mycouchdb` (since `.` refers to the current node). When there is no alias yet with value "mycouchdb", `alias[.="mycouchdb"]` will not match anything and Augeas will create a node with label `alias` and value `mycouchdb`. When there there is an alias already, the expression will match and the set command will replace the value with `mycouchdb`, which will do nothing.

Comment: I get the first bit, and that is what I thought the patterns mean, but it is the when it does not match bit, that I am confused about. What are the rules for that? Also could you update the answer, then I can ✓ it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the rule when the node doesn't exist is to use the path label without filters, in this case `alias`, so it creates a new `label` node and assigns it the value `mycouchdb`.

Answer (score 1):

## To do the specific task of “find the node with `ipaddr` of `127.0.0.1` and add an alias to it”

Do

`augtool -b -s set '/files/etc/hosts/*[ipaddr = "127.0.0.1"]/alias[last()+1]' mycouchdb`

This looks in file `/etc/host/` any node(`*`), that has a sub-node of `ipaddr=127.0.0.1` and adds an `alias` of `mycouchdb`

## Documentation

The path is explained here https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/wiki/Path-expressions it uses XPath.

Sorry I can't find anything else good.